# looking for a JSP tag that truncate text

Tags: jsp, jsp-tags

Is there a ready-made JSP tag that truncate text to a given length, without breaking the word in the middle. instead find the next space.
e.g:
 - text = "aaa bbb ccc"
 - truncated text to 5 = "aaa bbb..."
 - truncated text to 2 = "aaa..."

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Look at [MMBase](http://www.mmbase.org/mmdocs/frontenddevelopers/taglib/reference.html#escaper) Library. These have such features

Comment: I don't see that escaper tag is capable of truncating text without breaking words. does it?